# $\int_0^\infty\frac{K_0(x)K_0(\alpha x)}{K_0(\beta x)}\cos xy\phantom{.}dx$ Integral from 1926 electrotechnical paper

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, special-functions, bessel-functions

Erdelyi et.al "Table of integral transforms, vol. I" on p. 50 cites the following integral 
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{K_0(x)K_0(\alpha x)}{K_0(\beta x)}\cos xy\phantom{.}dx,
$$
but instead of printing the result, they just gave a reference to the following article
http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01655994

Can anybody who has an access to this journal look it up and post the answer here (not the whole derivation, but just the answer, so knowledge of German is not needed. if there are Hankel functions $H_0^{(1)}$ instead of $K_0$ it doesn't matterr)? Thanks.

Comment: It's in German, and I don't read German. However, there is no integral like that in the paper. There is one that looks like it has the same form, but with Hankel $H_0^{(1)}$ functions in place of your modified second-kind Bessel function.

Comment: I don't read German either. @rajb245 Maybe the book got it wrong and the integral is in the first part http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01656706 ?

Comment: If $\alpha=\beta$ then the integral is ($\pi/2) (1+y^2)^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Perhaps trivial to you, but not to others looking for a start.

Comment: @Gromeko: I do read German, but I don't have the book. :-$)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't read German too well, but I think that the reason the formula is not given in Erdelyi et.al. is simply that it is not a simple closed formula. In the paper cited, I only see (after 5 minutes of browsing) the integral expressed as a series expansion (it is the cosine that is expanded), and it is not exactly the integral you look for (see below). Also, it is Hankel functions and not modified Bessel functions that are discussed.

Let me give some short details on the integral that vaguely looks like the one you ask for.

Formula (19) reads.
$$
\varphi_2=-\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{h}i\int_0^{+\infty}
\frac{H_0^{(1)}(i\alpha)H_0^{(1)}(i\alpha\rho/h)}{H_0^{(1)}(i\alpha\rho_m/h)}\cos(\alpha x/h)\,d\alpha
$$
Then, quickly, they put $\rho=h$ and as far as I understand they continue with this throughout. **This means, I'm afraid, that the article does not really include the type of integral that you look for**. Let me anyway write some of the stuff in that article.

In formula (21), $\Theta_0$ is introduced as
$$
\Theta_0(\rho_m/h)=i\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{[H_0^{(1)}(i\alpha)]^2}{H_0^{(1)}(i\alpha\rho_m/h)}\,d\alpha,
$$
and on the bottom of page 82 it is said

> Die Funktion $\Theta_0$ ist durch bekannte Funktionen nicht
>   darstellbar. Wir müssen daher ihren Verlauf, auf den im folgenden
>   alles ankommt, numerisch diskutieren

Then it is calculated that $\Theta_0(1)=1$ (formula (24)) and $\Theta_0(0)=0$ (formula (26)).

After that, a series representation of $\varphi_2$ is obtained via a Maclaurin expansion of the cosine. The result (formula (34)) is
$$
\varphi_2=-\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{h}\biggl[\Theta_0-\sqrt{\frac{\rho_m/h}{1-\rho_m/(2h)}}\biggl\{\frac{\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{2}\Bigl(\frac{x}{h}\Bigr)^2}{\Bigl(2-\frac{\rho_m}{h}\Bigr)^2}-
\frac{\frac{7\cdot 5\cdot 3\cdot 1}{8\cdot 6\cdot 4\cdot 2}\Bigl(\frac{x}{h}\Bigr)^4}{\Bigl(2-\frac{\rho_m}{h}\Bigr)^4}
+-\cdots\biggr\}\biggr]
$$

Note that there is no $\rho$ here ($\rho_m$ is something different)...

I don't have the motivation to dig deeper into this at the moment. I hope you got the information you looked for. Otherwise, please comment and I'll see if I can put some more light on the issue...

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer. It confirms my doubt that this integral doesn't have a closed form and as you noted explains why this formula is not given in the Erdelyi's book.